# Clickhouse variation percentage between beginning and end of intervals

Tags: clickhouse

I would like to compute the variation percentage of time intervals in Clickhouse, more precisely to have a timeseries of variation percentages of the values in a table between the beginning and the end of each minute of a day.

Here is what I have tried:

```
WITH beginning as
    (SELECT toStartOfInterval(toDateTime(mydatetime), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) as beginningOfInterval,
        sum(count(*)) OVER (Rows BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as totalBeginningOfInterval
    FROM mytable
        WHERE datetime>='2023-08-01 00:00:00' and datetime<='2023-08-01 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY beginningOfInterval
        ORDER BY beginningOfInterval asc)
, ending as
    (SELECT date_add(MINUTE, 1,toStartOfInterval(toDateTime(mydatetime), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) as endOfInterval,
            sum(count(*)) OVER (Rows BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as totalEndOfInterval
        FROM mytable
            WHERE datetime>='2023-08-01 00:00:00' and datetime<='2023-08-01 23:59:59'
            GROUP BY endOfInterval
            ORDER BY endOfInterval asc
    )
SELECT (ending.totalEndOfInterval - beginning.totalBeginningOfInterval) / (beginning.totalBeginningOfInterval + 1) * 100 as percentage,
 beginning.totalBeginningOfInterval, beginning.timeBeginningOfInterval from beginning, ending
```

"beginning" computes the value of the start of the one minute interval, "ending" computes the value of the end of the one minute interval and the last select computes the variation percentage between both of them.

What is important to understand here is that in the table "mytable" there can be any number of rows during the one minute intervals, hence the sum(count(*)) and the group by clauses.

Do you think this does the trick, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a request that does the trick elegantly: it avoids requesting the table twice, once for the beginning sample, once for the ending sample. And it shows without a doubt the variation sample that I was looking for (at the expected time period), which is so high that it is an outlier that should be spotted.

```
SELECT toStartOfInterval(toDateTime(mydatetime), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) as timeBeginningOfInterval,
        count() as totalBeginningOfInterval,
        avg(totalBeginningOfInterval) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MovingAverageLast,
        avg(totalBeginningOfInterval) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND 5 PRECEDING) AS MovingAverageBeforeLast,
        (MovingAverageLast - MovingAverageBeforeLast) / (MovingAverageBeforeLast + 1) * 100 as variationPercentage
    FROM mytable
        WHERE mydatetime>='2023-08-01 00:00:00' and mydatetime<='2023-08-01 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY timeBeginningOfInterval
        ORDER BY timeBeginningOfInterval asc
```

Give this to a Jupiter notebook and you'll be happy!